# Big-Oh of n! and n to the power of some exponent - question

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, factorial

Why do we have:

$k=3$

$ f(n) = \binom{n}{k} => f(n) $ is $ θ(n^3) $

Is the three in the binomial coefficient of importance, or is this true for all $k \leq n$ ?

Comment: Have you tried writing out the binomial coefficient as a function of $n$?

Comment: $\binom{n}{3}=\frac{n!}{3!(n-3)!}=\frac16n(n-1)(n-2)=\frac16n^3-\frac12n^2+\frac13n=\theta(n^3)$

Comment: Aah, ofcourse... Thank you!